# How do I get a function pointer from a trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, function-pointers

How do I get over something like this:

```
struct Test {
    foo: Option<fn()>
}

impl Test {
    fn new(&mut self) {
        self.foo = Option::Some(self.a);
    }

    fn a(&self) { /* can use Test */ }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: attempted to take value of method `a` on type `&mut Test`
 --> src/main.rs:7:36
  |
7 |             self.foo = Option::Some(self.a);
  |                                          ^
  |
  = help: maybe a `()` to call it is missing? If not, try an anonymous function
```

How do I pass a function pointer from a trait? Similar to what would happen in this case:

```
impl Test {
    fn new(&mut self) {
        self.foo = Option::Some(a);
    }
}

fn a() { /* can't use Test */ }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few mistakes with your code. new function (by the convention) should not take self reference, since it is expected to create Self type.

But the real issue is, `Test::foo` expecting a function type `fn()`, but `Test::a`'s type is `fn(&Test)` == `fn a(&self)` if you change the type of `foo` to `fn(&Test)` it will work. Also you need to use function name with the trait name instead of `self`. Instead of assigning to `self.a` you should assign `Test::a`.

Here is the working version:

```
extern crate chrono;

struct Test {
    foo: Option<fn(&Test)>
}

impl Test {
    fn new() -> Test {
        Test {
            foo: Some(Test::a)
        }
    }

    fn a(&self) {
        println!("a run!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = Test::new();
    test.foo.unwrap()(&test);
}
```

Also if you gonna assign a field in `new()` function, and the value must always set, then there is no need to use `Option` instead it can be like that:

```
extern crate chrono;

struct Test {
    foo: fn(&Test)
}

impl Test {
    fn new() -> Test {
        Test {
            foo: Test::a
        }
    }

    fn a(&self) {
        println!("a run!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = Test::new();
    (test.foo)(&test); // Make sure the paranthesis are there
}
```

Comment: Also you can use `Self` (capital S) in traits and impls. In your case for example you can change `new` function's return type to `Self` instead of keep repeating `Test`.

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do here is get a function pointer from a (to use Python terminology here, since Rust doesn't *have* a word for this) bound method.  You can't.

Firstly, because Rust doesn't have a concept of "bound" methods; that is, you can't refer to a method with the invocant (the thing on the left of the `.`) already bound in place.  If you want to construct a callable which approximates this, you'd use a closure; *i.e.* `|| self.a()`.

However, this *still* wouldn't work because closures *aren't function pointers*.  There is no "base type" for callable things like in some other languages.  Function pointers are a single, specific kind of callable; closures are completely different.  Instead, there are traits which (when implemented) make a type callable.  They are `Fn`, `FnMut`, and `FnOnce`.  Because they are traits, you can't use them as types, and must instead use them from behind some layer of indirection, such as `Box<FnOnce()>` or `&mut FnMut(i32) -> String`.

Now, you *could* change `Test` to store an `Option<Box<Fn()>>` instead, but that still wouldn't help.  That's because of the other, *other* problem: you're trying to store a reference to the struct inside of itself.  This is *not* going to work well.  If you manage to do this, you effectively render the `Test` value permanently unusable.  More likely is that the compiler just won't let you get that far.

> **Aside**: you *can* do it, but not without resorting to reference counting and dynamic borrow checking, which is out of scope here.

So the answer to your question as-asked is: you don't.

Let's change the question: instead of trying to crowbar a self-referential closure in, we can instead store a callable that *doesn't* attempt to capture the invocant at all.

```
struct Test {
    foo: Option<Box<Fn(&Test)>>,
}

impl Test {
    fn new() -> Test {
        Test {
            foo: Option::Some(Box::new(Self::a)),
        }
    }

    fn a(&self) { /* can use Test */ }

    fn invoke(&self) {
        if let Some(f) = self.foo.as_ref() {
            f(self);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = Test::new();
    t.invoke();
}
```

The callable being stored is now a function that takes the invocant explicitly, side-stepping the issues with cyclic references.  We can use this to store `Test::a` directly, by referring to it as a free function.  Also note that because `Test` is the implementation type, I can also refer to it as `Self`.

> **Aside**: I've also corrected your `Test::new` function.  Rust doesn't have constructors, just functions that return values like any other.

If you're confident you will never want to store a closure in `foo`, you can replace `Box<Fn(&Test)>` with `fn(&Test)` instead.  This limits you to function pointers, but avoids the extra allocation.

If you haven't already, I *strongly* urge you to read [the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).